# dataframe column wise subtraction and division.

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, matrix, apply

need help in N number or column wise subtraction and division, Below are the columns in a input dataframe.

```
input dataframe:

> df
    A B C D
1   1 3 6 2
2   3 3 3 4
3   1 2 2 2
4   4 4 4 4
5   5 2 3 2


formula - a, (b - a) / (1-a)

MY CODE 
ABC <- cbind.data.frame(DF[1], (DF[-1] - DF[-ncol(DF)])/(1 - DF[-ncol(DF)]))

Expected out: 
  A    B     C    D
  1  Inf   -1.5  0.8
  3  0.00   0.0 -0.5
  1  Inf    0.0  0.0
  4  0.00   0.0  0.0
  5  0.75  -1.0  0.5
```

But i dont want to use ncol here, cause there is a last column after column D in the actual dataframe.

So want to apply this formula only till first 4 column, IF i use ncol, it will traverse till last column in the dataframe. 
Please help thanks.

Comment: so `df[1:4]` would work?

Comment: ohh yes, ....didnt thought of that thankyou Sotos. But i really dont want to use the ncol want to know some other ways to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about trying:

```
df <- matrix(c(1,3,6,2,3,3,3,4,1,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,5,2,3,2), nrow = 5, byrow = TRUE)
df_2 <- matrix((df[,2]-df[,1])/(1-df[,1]),5,1)
df_3 <- matrix((df[,3]-df[,2])/(1-df[,2]),5,1)
df_4 <- matrix((df[,4]-df[,3])/(1-df[,3]),5,1)
cbind(df[,1],df_2,df_3,df_4)
```

edit:  a loop version

```
df <- matrix(c(1,3,6,2,3,3,3,4,1,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,5,2,3,2), nrow = 5, byrow = TRUE)
test_bind <- c()
test_bind <- cbind(test_bind, df[,1])
for (i in 1:3){df_1 <- matrix((df[,i+1]-df[,i])/(1-df[,i]),5,1)
    test_bind <- cbind(test_bind,df_1)}
    test_bind
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map2_df(DF[2:4], DF[1:3], ~ (.x - .y)/(1- .y)) %>%
        bind_cols(DF[1], .)
#  A    B    C    D
#1 1  Inf -1.5  0.8
#2 3 0.00  0.0 -0.5
#3 1  Inf  0.0  0.0
#4 4 0.00  0.0  0.0
#5 5 0.75 -1.0  0.5
```